# Pourquoi « la prononciation du français » mais « un cours de français » ?

Tags: grammaire, usage, articles, possessif

Pourquoi utilise-t-on « du » pour [le premier](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais) mais « de » pour [le dernier](http://www.france-langue.fr/)?

Est-ce que des règles spécifiques existent pour cet usage ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

« Le français » et « français » ne sont pas interchangeables.

Beaucoup des combinaisons sont possibles:

> La prononciation du français. (= « de le français » = de la langue française).

= Comment prononce-t-on la langue française.

> La prononciation de « français ».

= Comment prononce-t-on « français » (le mot, ici un adjectif).

> Un cours du Français. (= « de le » Français = une personne)

= Un cours donné par « le » Français (on suppose que les autres enseignants ne le sont pas).

> Un cours de français.

= Un cours où l'on enseigne le français (pas d'article après « cours de, lesson de, faute de, etc. » : un cours de mathématiques, de sport, une lesson de morale, une faute de français) mais:

> Un cours du soir.

= Un cours qui a lieu le soir (la matière enseignée n'est pas « le soir »).

Comment: Merci pour l'explication détaillée ! Ça m'a éclairé beaucoup.

Comment: Alors n'hésite pas à valider. ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Les règles à suivre sont les suivantes :**

***Si on ne parle pas de QUANTITÉ :***

*Règle à suivre n°1 * : De + nom masculin == > du

***Exemples*** :

- Je bois du lait.
- J'ai du travail.
- Je veux du silence.

*Règle à suivre n°2* :De + article + nom féminin ==> de la

***Exemples*** :

- J'exige de la tranquillité.
- Je mange de la pizza.

***Si on parle de QUANTITÉ :***

*Règle à suivre* :Article + Nom + "de" ou bien "d'" + nom (Masculin ou Féminin)

***Exemples*** :

- J'ai besoin d'une tasse de café.
- Il m'a servi une assiette de viande.
- J'ai beaucoup de travail.
- Passez-moi la bouteille d'eau.

***Répondons maintenant concrètement à ta question tout en appliquant ces règles :***

*La prononciation du français* ( Pas de quantité, français est masculin, d'où " de + nom masculin " devient "du"

*Un cours de français* ( Quantité, donc on met soit "de" soit "d'", il s'agit d'un "F", consonne donc, le choix est "de")

Voilà :)

Comment: Merci pour la réponse ! Mais alors pourquoi « un professeur de français » ? Un professeur ne me semble pas une unité de quantité.

Comment: Je pense que c'est relatif au fait que le nom en question soit défini ou pas. Par exemple, quand tu dis chef de département, c'est indéfini. Par contre, si tu précises de quel département précisément il s'agit, par exemple "informatique", dans ce cas, tu diras, le chef de département d'informatique.

Comment: Mais, le chef du "Département d'Informatique" versus le "Chef de Departement" d'Informatique.

Comment: Non, je m'excuse, j'ai fait une faute d'inattention dans mon message du 24. Je voulais dire : Chef DE département parce qu'on n'a pas défini de quel département précisément il est question. Par contre, chef DU département d'informatique, parce qu'on a rajouté une précision.